# Hostname in _document.js file in nextJS project

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to get hostname in _document.js file in nextJS. window object is not accessible in server-side rendering.

Tried to get it from initialProps (context), but req in initialProps is undefined.

Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In the server-side environment, you can inject the hostname from the request object and make it available as a `prop` to `_document`. Here is a basic example using a class component in Typescript to achieve it.

```js
class MyDocument extends Document<propType> {

  static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext): Promise<propType> {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

    return {
      ...initialProps,
      host: ctx.req?.headers?.host,
    }
  }
  render() {
    const hostname = this.props.host // hostname is injected as prop
    return (
      // Your Markup here
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried this already. "req" and "res" from context is always undefined unless there is any error.